# Threading with Tkinter to introduce Progress bar

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I would like to introduce 'Indeterminate progress bar' for each of these two functions. Is there anyway to achieve it using Threading or any other method?

```
import threading
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import time


def submit_button1():
    i=0
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(2) 
        i+=1
    messagebox.showinfo("", "Completed")

def submit_button2():
    j=0
    for j in range(5):
        time.sleep(3) 
        j+=1
    messagebox.showinfo("", "Completed")
    

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x300")
root.title("Progress Bar")
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="submit_button1", command=submit_button1).grid(column=3, row=12, sticky=W)
    
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="submit_button2", command=submit_button1).grid(column=3, row=15, sticky=W)
    
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea was already correct. Just open a thread about an extra function. For the progress bar it is necessary to define a style and pass it to the widget. If you want to show the progress in the progress bar, then you need to define another style. For this it is enough to add a letter or a number in `text.Horizontal.TProgressbar` and change the name of the style. In this example, I disabled the button until the `Messagebox.showinfo` appears and then enabled the button again. Otherwise you would open a new thread every time you press the button and that could lead to errors. If you want to set a boundray you can also use `semaphore`, but for that I recommend to read the documentation.

```
import threading
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import time

class pseudo_example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("600x300")
        self.root.title("Progress Bar")

    def submit_button1(self):
        self.bu1["state"] = "disable"
        i = 0
        for i in range(101):
            time.sleep(.1)
            self.progressbar_1["value"] = i
            i += 1
        messagebox.showinfo("", "Completed")
        self.bu1["state"] = "normal"
        self.progressbar_1["value"] = 0


    def submit_button2(self):
        self.bu2["state"] = "disable"
        i = 0
        for i in range(101):
            time.sleep(.1)
            self.progressbar_2["value"] = i
            i += 1
        messagebox.showinfo("", "Completed")
        self.bu2["state"] = "normal"
        self.progressbar_2["value"] = 0

    def thread_sub1(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.submit_button1, daemon=True).start()

    def thread_sub2(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.submit_button2, daemon=True).start()

    def display(self):
        self.bu1 = ttk.Button(self.root, text="submit_button1", command=self.thread_sub1)
        self.bu1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

        self.bu2 = ttk.Button(self.root, text="submit_button2", command=self.thread_sub2)
        self.bu2.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar', anchor='center', troughcolor='white',
                        background='#009999')
        self.progressbar_1 = ttk.Progressbar(self.root, style='text.Horizontal.TProgressbar')
        self.progressbar_1.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

        self.progressbar_2 = ttk.Progressbar(self.root, style='text.Horizontal.TProgressbar')
        self.progressbar_2.grid(column=1, row=1)


        self.root.mainloop()


start = pseudo_example()
start.display()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). Maybe you could also explain how to introduce Inderminate Progress bars here for both functions. Sorry but I am new to Python programming hence asking this.

Comment: If you read my question and heading carefully, I asked to introduce Inderminate Progress bars for the functions :). Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: I hope u can work with my solution